# Update array in C with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a function that has the following structure

```
void calculate_grades(double* total, int n, int* grades){
     // n: number of students
     // total: scores of students (on a scale of 0-100)
     // grades: grades of students (0->A, 1->B, etc.)
     int local_grades[n];

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        // operations to find the grade
        local_grades[i] = result; //calculated grade inside this loop
   }
  // point grades to local_grades
  *grades = test_grades[0];

 for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
    test_grades[i] = *grades;
    grades++;
    printf("%d", *grades);
  }
}
```

I'm getting a bus error:10 here. What I am trying to do is have grades point to the actual grades calculated then be able to use that somewhere else. So essentially when I call grades[i] somewhere else in a loop I want to be able to see that actual grades (0 or 1 etc.) and not the addresses? 
Having the function like this:

```
void calculate_grades(double* total, int n, int* grades){
     // n: number of students
     // total: scores of students (on a scale of 0-100)
     // grades: grades of students (0->A, 1->B, etc.)
     int local_grades[n];
   grades = (int*) calloc(n, sizeof(int));

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        // operations to find the grade
        grades[i] = result; //calculated grade inside this loop
        printf("%d", grades[i]);
   }
}
```

Gives me the right input inside the function but not elsewhere. Any help please?

This is my main:

```
int main(){
  double scores[10]={34, 24.4, 23.7, 12, 35.4, 64, 2, 45, 88, 11};
  int n = 10;
  int* grades;
  int i;

  calculate_grades(scores, n, grades);
  printf("MAIN FUNCTION");

 for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("%d\n", grades[i]);
 }
   return 0;
}
```

And this is a sample output I get

```
2
3
3
3
2
1
4
2
0
3
MAIN FUNCTION 
25
552
1163157343
21592
0
0
0
1
4096
0
```

Comment: Post [mcve]..............

Comment: I posted enough information for the actual problem I am having, didn't want to overload the post with irrelevant lines. What kind of clarifications you'd like me to add?

Comment: How you call the function? What the argument types? etc Read the linked paragraph.

Comment: Hint: where `grades` is pointing to?

Comment: my bad, sorry! I made some edit, I hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from `calculate_scores`:

```
grades = (int*) calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

Then change `int* grades;` to `int grades[n];` in `main`.

**Explanation:**

Right now you are passing the value of the unitialized pointer `grades` to the function `calculate_scores`. Then you allocate memory for an array, and override the value of the local pointer `grades` inside `calculate_scores` (which has absolutely no effect on the `grades` in `main`).

If you create the array in your `main` method instead and pass the address of that array to `calculate_scores`, like you already do with the `scores` array, the method can write to that array and you can access the values in `main`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

C is pass by value. You have made changes to the local copy of `grades` in the function `calculate_grades()`. Solution is to pass the address and then by dereferencing it you will make changes to the desired variable.:-

```
calculate_grades(scores, n, &grades);
```

And

```
void calculate_grades(double* total, int n, int** grades){
     int local_grades[n];
   *grades =  calloc(n, sizeof **grades);
   if(!(*grades)){
       perror("calloc failure");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   ...
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        (*grades)[i] = result; //calculated grade inside this loop
        printf("%d", (*grades)[i]);
   }
}
```

And your first code that you showed, was dereferencing a pointer whose content was indeterminate - which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you! Now I see what you meant by undefined behavior.